# How to parse HTML that is inside multiple class or headers names using python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am using `.find()` with BeautifulSoup to try and access text and values in html but it seems to be imbedded in a second layer instead of just being under a single "class". Here is my target:

```
<h6 class="var1">
    <span class="var2">number</span>
    <span class="var3">text1</span>
    <span class="var4">text2</span>
</h6>
```

I want to retrieve number, text1 and text2. For number I have tried using:

```
number=card.find('h6', {'class': 'var1'}).find('span', {'class': 'var2'}).text
```

But this results in nothing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `card`? I can't reproduce. `soup.find('h6', {'class': 'var1'}).find('span', {'class': 'var2'}).text` returns `'number'`, with `soup` being the entire HTML provided

Comment: In other words, provide a [mcve]

Comment: The target is contained within card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I pass html into the code, it produces the correct results. Therefore I would assume the HTML being passed,  doesn't contain the HTML markup that you expect. You can check this by running `print(card.prettify())`

This shows your code works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<h6 class="var1">
    <span class="var2">number</span>
    <span class="var3">text1</span>
    <span class="var4">text2</span>
</h6>"""

card = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(card.prettify()) # Have a look to see if your html contains the relavant html elements
number=card.find('h6', {'class': 'var1'}).find('span', {'class': 'var2'}).text
print(number)
```